# Creating Self Expiring Alphanumeric Id In php

Tags: php

I am creating a self expiring id, alphanumeric which can expire after a set time frame.
But i don't know how to do it in php.

Comment: IF you dont know HOW?.... How are you creating it?

Comment: Do you not know how to create a random alphanumeric string? Or how to make it expire?

Answer (score 0):

save a random numerical id AND a timestamp in the database. Check each time the id is used if the timestamp + timeout is in the past or future

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp),

```
setcookie("id", "XD67KJKKJK65DD", time()+3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`uniqid()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)** PHP function to generate the ID. As for the expiry period, save it in a database along with the time of expiry and test against it whenever the ID is used.

Answer (score 0):

SET a timestamp with all the alphanumeric ID's.

```
$id = array(id => 'id', "timeframe" => '23435476575');
```

Then check, when you need to.

```
if($id['timeframe'] < time()) {
   echo "expired";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely in lookout for this [Web Security : Using crumbs to protect your PHP API (Ajax) call from Cross-site request forgery (CSRF/XSRF) and other vulnerabilities](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/10/web-security-using-crumbs-to-protect-your-php-api-ajax-call-from-cross-site-request-forgery-csrfxsrf-and-other-vulnerabilities/)

This explains how you can create short, self expiring alpha numeric id's which you can validate on the backend before processing any request associated with them.